# Ruby on Rails where statement using user attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So basically I want something like this:

```
@network = Network.where(:id => current_user.network_ids).first
@posts = Post.where(:user.network.first => @network).order("created_at DESC")
```

But it basically doesn't recognize the column `:user` in the second line as the real column is `user_id`. I even tried:

```
@posts = Post.where('User.find(user_id).network.first =?',network )
```

with no luck

any ideas on how I could approach this.

model:

```
 class User
    has_and_belongs_to_many :network
    has_many :posts
  end
  class Network
    has_and_belongs_to_many :user
  end
  class Post
    belongs_to :user
  end
```

I basically want to filter the posts according to the network of the current user

Comment: In general terms, can you tell me what you are trying to do?

Comment: And how are your models connected.

Comment: Post your models code.

Comment: @ShamsulHaque model code posted

Comment: @SebastiánPalma model code posted

Comment: @Pavan I basically want to filter the posts according to the network of the current user

Answer (score 0):

So I simply solved the problem  by using:

```
@posts = Post.where('user_id = ?', @network.user_ids)
```

Comment: Well, none of this makes sense given your models or original question.

Answer (score -1):

As i can see, you have `posts` which belongs to a user and then `user` has many `networks` therefore your query should be

```
@posts = Post.where(:user.networks.first => @network).order("created_at DESC")
```

what your are calling is

```
:user.network.first
```

which states user has `has_one` relationship with network